# can not store record into array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have no idea why it is not working. basically what I want is, select all "`emp_no`" from `mysql table` and store in an array and to display every record.

```
    $selectresult = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT emp_no FROM empreg"); 
        $result_array = array();
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectresult))
     {
        $result_array[] = $row['emp_no'];
     }
     print_r($result_array);
```

I am getting empty result like :- `Array( )`

Comment: You are mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions...

Comment: We really need a community wiki for this issue - I've seen it *a lot* lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT emp_no FROM emp_reg");
```

You are only storing the mysqli query object into the $query variable. You are NOT creating an array which contains all the values of 'emp_no' in your database.
So that is why you do:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{

}
```

It loops through the array which mysqli_fetch_assoc() creates from your $query and stores in $row.
Another important note: DO NOT MIX MYSQLI FUNCTIONS WITH MYSQL FUNCTIONS. mysql_* has now become deprecated.

Finally, unless you need to store the values of the 'emp_no' for some other reason, there is really no reason to create an array to store them in, you can simply print them from within your loop. Like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $row['emp_no'] . "<br />";
}
```

Hope this helps you understand a little bit more anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
... 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectresult)) {
   ...    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// run query
$query = mysql_query($dbc,"SELECT emp_no FROM empreg");

// set array
$array = array();

// look through query
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

  // add each row returned into an array
  $array[] = $row;

  // OR just echo the data:
  echo $row['username']; // etc

}

// debug:
print_r($array); // show all array data
echo $array[0]['username']; // print the first rows username
```

i wish it's help you